# eval function in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, eval

I'm new to code igniter and I want to know how to use eval function in code igniter? When I try to use eval function in native php it works perfectly. But When I use the same code in code igniter it is throwing error.

```
eval("\$result = \"$jsonValues\";");
```

This is the error

syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in C:\wamp\www\xxx\yyy\search.php(32) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Any reason you have to use `eval`? Besides, it is nothing related with codeigniter.

Comment: using eval is not recommended! can you explain your requirement ?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to send a request to solr and getting a php response. Now I want to process returned values

Comment: I'm getting php response from solr. How to process the content in code igniter?

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval` all the time (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685637/processing-php-returned-using-file-get-contents) ? Same error with eval, don't create multiple posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use eval. But your code is failing because you aren't escaping the $ in $jsonValues

Comment: How should I need to escape $?

Comment: eval("\$results = \"\$jsonValues\";");